# PhpStorm Xdebug: execute line by line

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

How can I tell the PhpStorm's debugger to stop at every line without having to manually insert a line break on every line? I couldn't find this info online..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `F8` (*Step Over*) to execute the next statement without stopping into the functions (if there is any function call in the next statement).

Use `F7` (*Step Into*) to execute the next statement and enter the code of the functions. If there is any function call in the next statement, the debugger will stop on the first statement of the first function call.

Check the [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/debug-tool-window.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can put Breakpoint at the beginning of code and then go over each line with keyboard or debug panel

https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/debug-tool-window.html